# OpenCV iOS - Expected identifier (MACRO)

Tags: ios, opencv, opencv3.0, opencv3.1

Getting error from "opencv2.framework".
Just a new project contained "opencv2.framework" not running.

My Steps:

1. download latest opencv2.framework
2. add required frameworks
3. declare .pch file stuff
4. changed .m file -> .mm

**Am I missing something?**

[image]

```
#ifndef PrefixHeader_pch
#define PrefixHeader_pch

#import <Availability.h>

#ifndef __IPHONE_4_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 4.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif

#endif /* PrefixHeader_pch */
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Line 46 says it all: You have to put `opencv.hpp` before any Apple's headers. In `PrefixHeader.pch` move

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#endif
```

up and before

```
#import <Availability.h>
```